# Verify if an intent take a valid activity

Tags: java, android

```
public void action(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS);
    if(intent!=null) //here is my problem, it return true always
     {startActivity(intent);}
     else{k++;
         Context context = getApplicationContext();
         CharSequence mesajText = "Failed To Open! " + k;
         int duration = 3;
         Toast screen_message = Toast.makeText(context,mesajText,duration);
         screen_message.show();
         }
}
```

How can I verify if my 'intent' have a valid activity(works when it's open) or an invalid one(app crash when it's open)?

Comment: have you tried to put a  try ... catch` around the startActivity and put the Toast into the catch?

Answer (score 1):

`if(intent!=null)` will always evaluate to `true` because your are initializing intent just before the `if condition`. If you want to check if `Intent` can be handled then use `resolveActivity` as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS);
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
} else{
   k++;
   CharSequence mesajText = "Failed To Open! " + k;
   int duration = 3;
   Toast screen_message = Toast.makeText(this,mesajText,duration);
   screen_message.show();
}
```

Comment: And wou have any idea how can i open this : Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS (keeping the code above) ? it doesn't work, I must do somethig more to open Developer Options?